# Apply style on scrollable element

Tags: html, css, angular

I have data which i am displaying by columns with ngFor. When I add styles to column div, they are only applayd on 'visible' part of whole column, I can't see them when I scroll to the bottom. There must be height limit and sticky haders. I made stackblitz to show my problem.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bcsqc8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-padmfe?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css)

The **overflow-y** CSS property specifies whether to clip content, render a scroll bar, or display overflow content of a block-level element, when it overflows at the top and bottom edges.

```css
.main-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    flex-direction: row;
    position: relative;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

I found answer about sticky issue [here](https://blog.cloud66.com/position-sticky-problem/).

if your element isn't sticking as expected the first thing to check are the rules applied to the container.

Specifically, look for any overflow property set on the parent. You can't use: `overflow: hidden`, `overflow: scroll` or `overflow: auto` on the parent of a position: sticky element.

So after removing `overflow: auto;` in the container, the sticky worked well

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}
```